# Elastic4s ngram mapping

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, mapping, elastic4s

I have to create an ElasticSearch mapping like this using elastic4s:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
       "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
       "fielddata": true
      },
      "lang": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "order": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "active": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
```

I can do

```
def mapping: Option[MappingDefinition] =
    Some(
      properties(
        KeywordField("id"),
        KeywordField("lang"),
        BasicField("order", "long"),
        BasicField("active", "boolean"),
        TextField("description")
      )
    )
```

for id, lang, order, active and description.
But, how can I do such mapping for `name`. the problem is `analyzer` and `fielddata` inside it.

Comment: Some examples can be found [here](https://sksamuel.github.io/elastic4s/docs/indices/createindex.html)

Comment: @Val, but they don't look like the examples I have

Comment: Have you tried `TextField("name").fielddata(true).analyzer("ngram_analyzer")` ?

Comment: @Val, it didn't work. Most probably, because you must describe "ngram" analyzer. Now the problem is how to describe analyzer)

Comment: Of course you need to do that (i.e. create your analyzer) in the settings section. But try to use `standard` instead and you'll see it should work.

Comment: @Val, yes, `standard` worked.

Comment: Cool, then this question is solved ;-) You can ask a new one for configuring the analyzer in the index settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
TextField("name").fielddata(true).analyzer("ngram_analyzer")
```

You also need to make sure to properly create the `ngram_analyzer` in your index settings.

Comment: thanks a lot. hope you'll answer to the next question too)

Comment: I think, I need your help there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984368/elastic4s-creating-settings-of-index